# mapply function does not work as expected

Tags: r, mapply

I am writing a large function. I would like to use `mapply` function to run a function over a lists.

I have this:

```
 x <- list(1,3, 4, 5)
 y <- list(5,6,7,3)
 res <- mapply(x  , y , FUN = function(x, y) double(x + y)) 
[[1]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[4]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I would like the result to be as a two lists only. Like this:

```
 [[1]]
0 0 0 0 0 

[[2]]
0 0 0 0 0
```

So I would like the answer to be for the two list only not for each element of the list.

how can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain your output, where do those two times 5 zero's come from? Right now the first element of your actual ouput is simply 6 zero's because `1 + 5 == 6`.

Comment: @missuse I tried it and got this: `> startpar
[1] 10 10`

Comment: @Axeman thank you for comment. I am really surprised like you. I do not understand why.

Comment: Why do you expect those results? For the first values of `x` and `y` you will have `double(1 + 5)`. That's a vector of zeros with length 6, not two vectors of length 5. I don't understand how you can expect vectors of length 5.

Comment: Since `mapply` fitted to two lists, so why I cannot get the two lists as output.

Comment: For each element of `x` and `y` you get output, they are mapped in parallel. I'm not surprised by the output you get, I'm confused about your expected output.

Comment: @RuiBarradas the output is wrong. So, the idea is that, I have two  lists  with 5 elements in each. Then, I would like to use `double` with them. The result, should be 5 zeros. for each list.

Comment: Something like: `lapply(list(x, y), function(l) double(length(l)))`? Or simply `lapply(lengths(list(x, y)), double)`. And your lists have four elements, not five!

Comment: @Axeman thanks a lot. I would like to have this: `double(x+y)` with `lapply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `lapply` function.

```
my_list(x,y)
m <- length(my_list)
lapply(1:m, function(i) double(x[[i]]+y[[i]]))
```

Your list length is 4 so you cannot except it to be two as output!